# HTTP GET request return err_connection_reset on Android

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, browser-cache, soti

First of all, I ask for a little understanding because it is not my field but I found myself working on it anyway.

We have an angular application compiled with ionic and distributed as an apk on Android devices used by a company.

It's a very simple application, but it requires you to make API calls to a private server to work.

From a certain day onwards, this application was no longer able to contact the API resulting in the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error.

This error was also evident on the Soti Surf browser (software used by the devices).
On Chrome, however, the API was reachable. (it seems to me that the application should use the Chrome webview)

Clearing the cache or reinstalling the application did not solve the problem.

Resetting the device solved the problem.

What hypotheses can I evaluate at this point? What could have been deleted with the reset that affected the HTTP request?